# How make branches in a Apache Airflow Dag?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have a dag like this (This is a semi-pseudocode), I want to execute the tasks in different branches based on their output.

```
#This is a method that return a or b
def dosth():
    .....
    return a or b

t1 = PythonOperator(
    't1',
    python_callable = dosth
)

branchA = BashOperator(
    'branchA',....
)

branchB = BashOperator(
    'branchB',....
)
```

What I want is if `dosth` returns a, I want the dag to execute the task in branchA, if it returns b,I want the dag to execute the task in branchB. Anyone knows how can we approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Check this doc about Branching: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=branch#branching

You need to use `BranchPythonOperator` where you can specify the condition to be evaluated to decide which task should be run next.

Example based on your semi-pseudocode:

```py
def dosth():
    if some_condition:
        return 'branchA'
    else:
        return 'branchB'

t1 = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='t1',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable= dosth,
    dag=dag)

branchA = BashOperator(
    'branchA',....
)

branchB = BashOperator(
    'branchB',....
)
```

The function you pass to `python_callable` should return the `task_id` of the next task that should run.

Another Example:

```py
def branch_func(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    xcom_value = int(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='start_task'))
    if xcom_value >= 5:
        return 'continue_task'
    else:
        return 'stop_task'

start_op = BashOperator(
    task_id='start_task',
    bash_command="echo 5",
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)

branch_op = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branch_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=branch_func,
    dag=dag)

continue_op = DummyOperator(task_id='continue_task', dag=dag)
stop_op = DummyOperator(task_id='stop_task', dag=dag)

start_op >> branch_op >> [continue_op, stop_op]
```